# how do I render a star react icon using functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

Im learning functional components on react. Im creating a component that gets the average rating of a business and then shows it in stars. Im not sure if im using setState correctly or returning the react-icons correctly. Right now there are no errors,
props include reviews (objects with many reviews).

tldr, why is aiFillStars not showing rating/averageStars.

Thank you in advance.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {AiFillStar } from "react-icons/ai";

export default function Star(props) {
    const [rating, setRating] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        getAverageRating();
        // distributeStars();
    }, [rating]);

    const getAverageRating = () => {
        let totalStars = 0;
        props.reviews.forEach(review => {totalStars += review.rating});
        let averageStars = Math.ceil(totalStars / props.reviews.length);
        setRating(averageStars);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {Array(5).fill().map((_, i) => {
                const ratingValue = i + 1;
                <div>
                    <AiFillStar
                            className='star'
                            color={ratingValue <= rating ? "#ffc107" : "#e4e5e9"}
                            size={25} />
                </div>
            })}
        </div>
   );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely not displaying anything because you are not returning anything from your `array.map()`

```
{
  Array(5)
    .fill()
    .map((_, i) => {
      const ratingValue = i + 1;
      return (
        <div>
          <AiFillStar
            className="star"
            color={ratingValue <= rating ? "#ffc107" : "#e4e5e9"}
            size={25}
          />
        </div>
      );
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you! I put aiFillStarDiv in a return bracket.

Comment: got it. need to wait 2 minutes